# Aggregation between two derived classes

Tags: c++, aggregation

Can there be an aggregation relationship type between two derived classes of one base class (for example, one class contains vector of another)?

Can it be implemented in C++ and if so, is it considered a good practice and does not violate logic or not?

Example in picture: [image: class diagram]

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking here: Are you asking about how to draw this relationship in a diagram? (And if so, according to what rules, UML?) Are you asking how to describe the relationship in words? Are you asking whether it is possible to implement? (And if so, in what programming language?) Are you asking if it is a "good" design? (If so, the question is off-topic as opinion-based.)

Comment: @IMSoP I want to know if it can be implemented in C++ and if so, is it considered a good practice and does not violate logic or not?

Comment: As I mentioned already, whether something is "good practice" is probably a matter of opinion, so not a suitable question for this site as discussed in the [help]. I'm not really sure what "violating logic" would mean; is there some specific set of principles you are trying to adhere to, which this might violate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, and your class diagram shows an example of when you'd do this. Except buttons are actual, "physical" items on screen, and have unique identity, you can't just copy them in a data structure, you would *probably* use pointers to these buttons, in C++ like this using smart pointer:

```
std::vector <std::unique_ptr<Button> > buttons;
```

Using pointers also allows for example `MyWindow` contain other `MyWindow` without you getting compiler errors about incomplete type.

Comment: To be more specific, that should probably be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Button>>`. Raw pointers probably shouldn't be recommended to new C++ programmers.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yeah, added, because this is a generic case. Though an actual GUI framework might have built-in ownership mechanism, in which case you would not use smart pointer, because the "parent window" already would own its "child windows".

Comment: @hyde Thank you! Then I can do any operations on this pointer to the vector as if it's just a vector?

Comment: @alex_shevch Not sure what you mean, but it is not a "pointer to the vector", it is a vector containing (smart) pointers. If you use `std::unique_ptr`, you need to note they can't be copied, which makes it necessary to do some things in specific ways. You can ask another question, with actual code where the problem is, if you run into problems with that.